# Activity indicator dynamically changing color ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

Help me to resolve the issue or any third party available for activity indicator.

> **Activity indicator changing the color after we got the result**

Anyone did this before?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

next time please follow the recommendation in the Desdenova's comment. Apart from that you can simply change the [`color`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityindicatorview/1622836-color) property of [`UIActivityIndicatorView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityindicatorview).

Here is a simple playground code snippet, which changes the color after 2 seconds.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
        activityIndicator.style = .whiteLarge
        activityIndicator.color = .red

        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)

        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2)) {
            activityIndicator.color = .blue
        }
    }
}

let viewController = ViewController()
viewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: 667)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
```

Best,
Carsten